# Angularjs auto refresh momentjs fromnow date value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I am a new to UI development and i have to develop a page which has a number of posts with creation dates. The creation date is displayed relative to current time like '3 hours from now'

I refereed [this link](http://www.34m0.com/2012/07/angularjs-user-friendly-date-display.html) and was able to do that successfully.  But i want to refresh the from now value every 30 seconds.  How to do this.  The author has replied

> I would say you would have to take another
>   tac, and add an additional attribute to the scope - let's call it
>   reply.fromNow - and update that value within the controller
>   periodically using the moment library.

But i couldn't make much out of it.  Can someone help me out with this thing?  Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could put something like this in your controller:

```
var refreshDates = function() {
    $timeout(refreshDates, 30000);
};
refreshDates();
```

Basically, it just trigger's a `$scope.$apply()` every thirty seconds.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NGq7w/)

Answer (score 3):

I made a wrapper for momentjs https://github.com/jcamelis/angular-moment

```
<p moment-interval="5000">{{"2014-05-21T14:25:00Z" | momentFromNow}}</p>
```

I hope it works for you.